# Is it Possible to find out at What part of the Input matches with the Output In Lucene?

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net

I have a input named Alex which gives output in Lucene as Alexander John. Here Alex is partly matches with the Alex is partly matches with Alexander .How to retrieve the Word Alexander is there any provision there in Lucene?

Comment: Are you trying to find the matching terms within the body of the matched document? In the same way that the Lucene [highlighter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Highlighter/) utilities do this? In other words, are you trying to find _where_ in the document the matched terms are - so that you can also see _what_ they are - and maybe also extract them?

Comment: In Java's Lucene library, I would use something like `FastVectorHighlighter` to do this - there is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68239057/lucene-how-can-i-get-position-of-found-query/68246947#68246947). It looks like Lucene.NET has the equivalent class [here](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/da/dbb/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_vectorhighlight_1_1_fast_vector_highlighter.html), but I have never used it.

Comment: @andrewjames Thanks this is what i was looking for .I will go through and see.