# Lucene search or highlight field values in a document

Tags: lucene, document

The index document has some fields and each field has thousands of values. When the document is returned from the query, I want to further obtain the values of the "hit" contained in each field.

Currently, I use highlighter to loop through each field values

```
highlighter.setTextFragmenter(new SimpleFragmenter(1000));
final TokenStream tokenStream = analyzer.tokenStream(fieldName, new StringReader(fieldValue));
final CachingTokenFilter filter = new CachingTokenFilter(tokenStream);
final String fragment = highlighter.getBestFragment(filter, value);
if (fragment != null) {
  //TODO
}
```

It works, but the performance is poor.
Is there a better way to achieve the same result and better performance.
Thanks in advance.

More details here

Each document has ten fields, field-1, field-2,...field-10, and each field has 1000 different values, such as field-1: apple, pear, banada,...

I use MultipleFieldQueryParser, when searching for "apple" for example, there are hits on field-1 and field-3, so in the first step I get the expected documents, and in the second step, I want to get fields-1: "apple", field-3: "2 apples" for the top hit document.

For the second step, I loop through each value of field-1, which means running highlight 1000 times. I think there may be a shortcut, such as applying a query or filter for the field-1 in the selected document and getting "apple", only one query is required

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is poor performance in this case? And what would be acceptable? How are you creating the fields in the index? Specifically, are fields created with positional data, term vectors, etc; or are these created on-the-fly at query time? What version of Lucene are you using? Is there any additional information you can provide which may help to recreate the issue (and help verify if it can be improved)?

Comment: I have added more details, it might help

Comment: Thank you for the extra information. Unfortunately, it's difficult to say anything specific, because your notes are fairly high-level (and there is no code showing how you do any of this, or how you created the indexed data in the first place). Perhaps the following may given you some options/ideas: [Lucene how can I get position of found query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68239057/12567365)